# Obtener solo mes y dia mediante SELECT en SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Uso SQL server 2008 R2

Quiero hacer un simple `select` que mediante un `GETDATE()` muestre un formato de fecha específico sin año:

> dia/mes

Este `select` me da los valores pero en columnas separadas

```
SELECT MONTH(GETDATE()), Day(GetDate())
```

Necesito hacerlo pero en este formato de ejemplo: *dia 1 mes diciembre*

> Fecha
>   1/12

intenté este:

```
SELECT (MONTH(GETDATE())/ Day(GetDate())) as Fecha
```

el resultado es :

> Fecha
>   0

Comment: qué versión de SQL Server estás usando?

Comment: Temo que te está devolviendo cero porque en realidad estás dividiendo el mes entre el día en tu SELECT. Si quieres las fechas deberías concatenarlas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para SQL Server 2012+, lo mejor es usar `FORMAT`:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'dd/MM') Fecha;
```

Si no, puedes usar:

```
SELECT DATENAME(DAY,GETDATE()) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),MONTH(GETDATE())) Fecha
;
```

O también

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),GETDATE(),103) Fecha;
```

Con este último código, el resultado sería `01/12`

Comment: El último código es mejor, influye menos al servidor ya que no hace tantas operaciones como el format y/o el datename.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la función CONCAT:

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(GETDATE()), '/', Day(GetDate())) as Fecha
```

Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

A mi me funcionó mucho de esta forma:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy-MM-dd') as fecha;
```

Si lo haces con un campo y tabla en especifico:

```
SELECT FORMAT(nombre_campo,'yyyy-MM-dd') as fecha FROM nombre_tabla;
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto te puede servir

```
SELECT CAST(Day(GetDate()) AS VARCHAR(10) ) +'/'+ CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(10)) as Fecha
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas convertir primero a texto lo que te muestra para poder concatenar los resultados.

Para eso debes usar la función `CONVERT`. Aplicado a lo que tu quieres sería:

```
SELECT (CONVERT(varchar(3),DAY(GETDATE()))+'/'+ CONVERT(varchar(3),MONTH(GetDate()))) as Fecha
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias intentar con [CAST o CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) de datetime  con un Date Style, convertirlo a un varchar de 5 caracteres, para que te tome los primeros 5 caracteres de dd/mm/yyyy es decir tomaria dd/mm.

Ejemplo de dia/mes

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),GETDATE(),103) AS FECHA
```

Ejemplo de mes/dia

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),GETDATE(),101) AS FECHA
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SET LANGUAGE Spanish
SELECT CONCAT('día ', DAY(GETDATE()), ' mes ', DATENAME(month, GETDATE()))
```